# How to set up a PPPoE connection on a router which connects to the Internet through another router

Tags: networking, router, pppoe, bridge-router

My ISP has given me a router on which I **don't have permission to set up the configuration** (well, the important part at least. It's in ***bridge mode***, ISP says). To connect to the Internet, I have to create a **PPPoE connection on my computer**.

I want to connect another router which only handles this PPPoE connection.

**How can I make it hand everything else to the router in *bridge mode*?**

(I have to turn off DHCP, right? What about DNS, NAT and other settings?

Answer (score 1):

In bridge mode your router is just plain bridge with L2 ports which means your router PPPoE interface can't be assigned any IP address. You must somehow chnage your router to routing mode, connect cable to WAN port and configure PPPoE in the router dialer. Enable NAT on LAN(L2) interface with DHCP enabled to ease your life. This should do it.

Alternatively get another router with WAN port and PPPoE support.